# White and Black Reading and Writing BMP C++

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, pixel, bmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: What’s the simplest way to read and write BMP files using C++ on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199403/c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-read-and-write-bmp-files-using-c-on-windows)

So, I am a relative beginner and want to read in a bitmap image and get their individual pixel values (being 0 for black and 1 for white) and put them into an array. I have done research on this but everything is really advanced in dealing with the headers and all. I am perfectly open to using a new library or any windows commands. Also after reading I would like to be able to create a bmp with the same values (but not just copying). Just simple commands or somewhere to start would be great. My plan is to read and write on a pixel by pixel basis. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199403/c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-read-and-write-bmp-files-using-c-on-windows