# C++ How to create a large bitmap from a datalist stored in a deque?

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp, deque

I am building my first ever program in C++ over and over again.

The program is intended to create a picture, *a gradient* - with parameters of height `h`, width `l`, in pixels, and 4 parameters of density `Da, Db, Dc, Dd`.
This gradient is produced by '1 bit' pixels: they are black or white - and by the simplest error-diffusion algorithm (so-called "naive" sometimes),

`>> push the error on the next pixel of the line.`

After having performed an optimization (`deque` instead of `vector` allows bigger images to be created for ex.), I am stuck with a problem that I cannot solve for now:

My pixel values being stored in a `deque`, how do I transport them into a bitmap file?

I tried to understand the `EasyBMP` library but I couldn't find the solution.

In my code, you can see `line 33` that I tried (unsuccessfully) to make a .PBM header (Portable Bit Map)

Actually, I'd like to copy the values of my `deque <int> dequeA;` (line 30)
to a `.BMP` file or any other raster file-format, instead of in a `.txt` file like it happens line 72!

Here's my code, and a nice picture of what it makes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// constant values

double   Da=1;          //densities
double   Db=0.5;
double   Dc=0.5;
double   Dd=0;

double      l = 999;    //width & height => L = l+1  ///  999 = 1000 pixels
double      h = 999;

//double      u = 1;    // UNIT

double      D = 0;      // GAMMA
double      E = 0;      // ERROR LOCAL
vector <double> F;      // ERROR DYNAMIC

int main ()
{
    // vector
    deque <int> dequeA;
    F.push_back (0);

    //dequeA.push_back (2);     //FAKE PBM header (old)
    //dequeA.push_back (l+1);
    //dequeA.push_back (h+1);
    //dequeA.push_back (1);

    float a = 0;
    float b = 0;                // Local variables
    double IO = 0;              // variable I/O

    while (a<l+1, b<h+1){

        //values for given a & b
        double DL = Da-Da*(b/h)+Dc*(b/h);
        double DR = Db-Db*(b/h)+Dd*(b/h);
        double D  = DL-DL*(a/l)+DR*(a/l); //GAMMA

        if (E+0-D<=-0.5) {
            dequeA.push_back(1);
            IO = 1;
        }

        else {
            dequeA.push_back(0);
            IO = 0;
        }

        E = E+IO-D;
        F.push_back(E);

        // next pixel & next line
        a++;
        if (a>l) {
            a = 0;
            b = b++;
            E = 0;
            F.clear();
        }
    }
    //export values to .txt file
    ofstream output_file("./test.txt");
    ostream_iterator<int> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    copy(dequeA.begin(), dequeA.end(), output_iterator);
    dequeA.clear();
}
```

[image: simplest error-diffusion with 4 corner-located density parameters]

Comment: Slightly old, but almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199403/c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-read-and-write-bmp-files-using-c-on-windows

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that in 2008 you were there, and now you are probably a much better programmer! :) Did you try the CImage Class?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but in 2008 I wasn't there, and I haven't tried that class either. I just suspected there might be duplicates of the question and found the above. Hope it helps.

Comment: _deque instead of vector allows bigger images to be created for ex._ - Care to elaborate? As long as you only `push_back` like in the sample you posted, `vector` would always be the better choice.

Comment: well `vector` need a free segment of memory, `deque` stores anywhere in available memory, wich makes more memory available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBM files are very easy to create and should suffice for your purpose. No need to use an external library.

A problem in your original code was that you were storing both the PBM metadata and the actual image data in the same `dequeA`. Don't do that. Mixing data like this makes your program hard to understand and maintain.

You can create a valid PBM file by slightly adjusting the code writing the file:

```
ofstream output_file("./test.ppm");

// write file header
output_file << "P1\n" << (l+1) << " " << (h+1) << "\n";
//write image data
ostream_iterator<int> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
copy(dequeA.begin(), dequeA.end(), output_iterator);
```

The resulting PPM file works fine with Gimp.

Writing to a BMP or TGA file works basically the same - you first write a header, followed by the actual data. The main difference is that those file formats are binary files, so the file I/O looks a bit different, and the header and image data formats are slightly more complicated. But still, both formats are quite simple and easy to write even without using a library.

Comment: Great great! Thanks so much, that's exactly what I was searching for!