# how to put char and long integer in txt file

Tags: c++, char, int, output, deque

I am stuck with this simple problem:

I want to create a text file (txt) as follows:

1st, I want to have characters:  the expression `P2`

**next line**

then a few long integers:        `1000000`

**next line**

Then add a big list of values that were stored in a `deque` (either `1` or `0`)

I use this code (only a fragment here...)

```
//export values to .txt file
ofstream output_file("./YESv1.0.pbm");
ostream_iterator <int> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
copy(dequeA.begin(), dequeA.end(), output_iterator);        //values
dequeA.clear();
```

My problem? I don't find how to imput the first lines (`'P2'\n` and the few `int`
`100000\n` before my values)

Thanks!

Comment: `ofstream` makes me think you're talking about C++, I'll add the tag.

Comment: SOLVED! actually solution was found there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583825/c-how-to-create-a-large-bitmap-from-a-datalist-stored-in-a-deque