# Change pixel to Symbols/Chars

Tags: c++

I want to try and make, in C++, a Program that takes an Image and scans pixel by pixel, for relatively Dark pixels it prints a space and for Light Pixels it prints symbols like:
"@#$%^!M()-~, etc" that will paint new picture with only symbols. 
I am new and I really would appreciate some guidance for how it is I can approach that,
I would like to *Surprise* my teacher. 
 
Thank you very much in advance.

ok that what i already had:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>       

BYTE* ConvertBMPToRGBBuffer(BYTE* Buffer, int width, int height)
{
    // first make sure the parameters are valid
    if ((NULL == Buffer) || (width == 0) || (height == 0))
        return NULL;

    // find the number of padding bytes

    int padding = 0;
    int scanlinebytes = width * 3;
    while ((scanlinebytes + padding) % 4 != 0)     // DWORD = 4 bytes
        padding++;
    // get the padded scanline width
    int psw = scanlinebytes + padding;

    // create new buffer
    BYTE* newbuf = new BYTE[width*height * 3];

    // now we loop trough all bytes of the original buffer, 
    // swap the R and B bytes and the scanlines
    long bufpos = 0;
    long newpos = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 3 * width; x += 3)
    {
        newpos = y * 3 * width + x;
        bufpos = (height - y - 1) * psw + x;

        newbuf[newpos] = Buffer[bufpos + 2];
        newbuf[newpos + 1] = Buffer[bufpos + 1];
        newbuf[newpos + 2] = Buffer[bufpos];
    }

    return newbuf;
}


BYTE* LoadBMP(int* width, int* height, long* size, LPCTSTR bmpfile)
{
    // declare bitmap structures
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpheader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpinfo;
    // value to be used in ReadFile funcs
    DWORD bytesread;
    // open file to read from
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(bmpfile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
    if (NULL == file)
        return NULL; // coudn't open file


    // read file header
    if (ReadFile(file, &bmpheader, sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bytesread, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    //read bitmap info

    if (ReadFile(file, &bmpinfo, sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bytesread, NULL) == false)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // check if file is actually a bmp
    if (bmpheader.bfType != 'MB')
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // get image measurements
    *width = bmpinfo.biWidth;
    *height = abs(bmpinfo.biHeight);

    // check if bmp is uncompressed
    if (bmpinfo.biCompression != BI_RGB)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // check if we have 24 bit bmp
    if (bmpinfo.biBitCount != 24)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }


    // create buffer to hold the data
    *size = bmpheader.bfSize - bmpheader.bfOffBits;
    BYTE* Buffer = new BYTE[*size];
    // move file pointer to start of bitmap data
    SetFilePointer(file, bmpheader.bfOffBits, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    // read bmp data
    if (ReadFile(file, Buffer, *size, &bytesread, NULL) == false)
    {
        delete[] Buffer;
        CloseHandle(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    // everything successful here: close file and return buffer

    CloseHandle(file);

    return Buffer;
}



void main()
{


    int x, y;
    long s, s2;
    BYTE* a = LoadBMP(&x, &y, &s, L"20140626_143101.bmp);
    BYTE* b = ConvertBMPToRGBBuffer(a, x, y);
    // what now??

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
}
```

after i convert the BMP to RGB Buffer what i can do next?? to check about the buffer if it dark or light pixels

Comment: Frist if your talking about c++ why C tag? Also what have you tried so far? ALso you don't impress your teacher if you don't learn this by yourself!

Comment: you right i remove the C tag, i didnt try anything so far, i dont know how to get Pixels from Image

Comment: You need to flesh out more of the details... what image format are you planning on using? If it's compressed (jpeg, png, etc.), you'll  need to decompress it in your code as well.

Comment: i found that thing:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/467586/Converting-image-file-to-text-using-c-programming
as the solution 3 said to change pixel with chars
and no care which Picture file, i mean all Picture types are good for me

Comment: you'd better learn a bmp library first. after you can use the library, your task should be easy. hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199403/c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-read-and-write-bmp-files-using-c-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

I would like to set you on the correct path, that is, without giving you the entire answer. I have found some references which will take you to what it is you would like to learn.

 
Firstly, one must decode the image. That is copy the image into a variable in another, readable, format. Writing one of these, especially when knew to C++, is not a good idea. But there are many libraries which do this very thing. I recommend: 
 
http://cimg.sourceforge.net/ and then as brief tutorial: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wittman/hyper/vick/Cimg_tutorial.pdf and Proceeding That to Edit a Single Pixel: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__loops.html (Look at the: **Loops over interior regions and borders** section)

This hopefully will point you in the right direction.
P.S. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: i have to do it without download any library or software
i have that Misson with do it with only C++ Libraries

Comment: Alright, that is going to make it very hard. How much time do you have? Because, it is going to take a very long time. Admittedly, I admire your goals.

Comment: Because, like I said, it is very time consuming to make your own parser. I will link you to a few websites when I get time.